# Removing Figure: from some pictures

Tags: captions

I've searched the web, but I didn't have any luck with this. 
I have two pictures in a document, and I would like for one to have a caption, and for the other not to have one.

So far I've only found how to remove the caption, but the 'Figure 1' part will still stay, and I want that to be gone as well, but still to be able to have a caption on the second figure.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well just remove the `\caption` command entirely. If yo don't have such a command in your document you might consider to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Oh! I was getting the error due to hypcap package! I didn't noticed that :
It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise you could use `\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}`

Comment: Package `hypcap` gives an example for a figure without caption using `\capstartfalse ...\capstarttrue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a caption only if you define one. But maybe I'm missing something. In the following example I used the figure-environment, but you can include graphics without using figure, when you want to place the figure exactly 'here'.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some Text

% Figure without caption
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

More Text

%Figure with caption 
\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```